# Are there any affordable resources to learn Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2-cloud

I am trying to learn Magento cloud to build docker image and deploy to cloud, I can't find resources to learn, I checked Adobe learning but the course is expensive $2700
any recommendations?

Comment: Anything on udemy?

Comment: Udemy has courses for general Magento developer, but not for specific Cloud track, I have good DevOps and Cloud knowledge and I read some of Magento documentation related to Magento Cloud, from what I read I assume that there are much missing information about how Magento Cloud is architected and how to develop